# usb not working-get error message no authorised ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb

USB not working in Ubuntu 18 new install. error message -"not authorised to perform operation" when I attempt to access connected device now working normally-removed chrome remote.

Comment: Are you reading the device, or writing to the device? Is this a storage device, or something else?

Comment: Its  usb memory sticks

Comment: Reading *and* writing? Or just writing? On all USB sticks? Or just one? On all of your USB ports? Or just one or two USB ports?

Comment: Now working normally - removed chrome remote extension